# how does XML GUID works?

Tags: xml, guid

Im working with office 2010. Under word, i can create a source XML file that contains all the books to insert into the bibliography. The thing is that i have to enter each book manually in word. I was thinking of creating a database that contains all these informations. From there i can handle.

I have noticed that the XML document contain a line with a GUID that looks like this;

```
<b:Guid>{08AA96E5-F22B-4FA2-8A17-31841871A9F5}</b:Guid>
```

It is word that placed this entry into the file and they are unique to each entry. Now if i want to create that xml file with a database how do i know what should be the value of the GUID. For that i need to understand whats the GUID and how is it created.

How do i know what is the value of the GUID or can it just be anything?
im planning on using MySQL or Access to create this Database.

------ UPDATE ------

By using Access i can make a GUID with this function `=GUIDFromString(string)`

Where sting could be anything. how could i pass a field named title as a string value to this field?

Anyone have tips on that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A GUID is a 128bit identifier and normally fully random. Depending on the language you are using there are several functions to generate a GUID.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for more details.